# Spinbox change values on keypress in qml

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to automatically change the value of the spinbox on keypress instead of enter? The problem is the following, lets suppose we go to the input where we have the number one:
[image]

And now i change it to number 10, but dont click on `enter`:

[image]

Now i click on the plus sign and it goes to number two:

[image]

How can this be changed in a way that when i loose focus, or click in the minus or plus sign of the spinbox in automatically takes in account the last digited number?

This is what is happening with `QtQuick.Controls 2.0`

An example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    height: 200
    width: 400
    Item {
        id: page
        anchors.fill: parent
        width:parent.width
        height: parent.height
            Column{
                width:parent.width
                spacing:10
                SpinBox {
                    id: spinBox1


      width: 100
                height: 30
                stepSize: 1
                editable: true
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi! Do you have any code to replicate an example? You could play with the `spinBox.currentValue` when it's changed, alternatively if your spin box values aren't too high, you could always disable the input so users can only use the plus/minus?(depends on use) If you post a small example of code we can run may be able to give an answer! :)

Comment: Yes @Ldweller I took this from a small workable example of a spinbox, but this is the way a default spinbox works I just need to check from which version of controls it was.

Comment: Hi @Nmaster88 I am still working to find a solution for you, I have removed my answer for now, and hopefully can post a working fix soon for you!

Comment: Thank u so much @Ldweller, i've been trying to find a solution, but my skills on this are still not much

Answer (score 1):

You could use the property "contentItem" of SpinBox and adding a TextInput.
The TextInput has the signal handler "onTextChanged".

```
SpinBox {
            id: spinbox
            value: 10
            editable: true
            contentItem: TextInput {
                text: spinbox.textFromValue(spinbox.value, spinbox.locale)
                font: spinbox.font
                horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
                readOnly: !spinbox.editable
                validator: spinbox.validator
                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
                onTextChanged: {
                   spinbox.value =  parseInt(text);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is seems to work well :P, but it looses the blue focus of the default spinbox, is there a way to get it?